# Confirming your FB Conversion Pixel

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to test a Facebook ad by going through your checkout process and firing the conversion pixel to see a successful conversion in the Ads Manager reporting dashboard?

We setup the pixel, and spent about $100 on ads, and saw 0 conversions. We can't tell if it's really not working, or if our ad is just not good.

Is there any way to confirm the pixel works by simulating (or actually) performing a successful checkout?

Comment: Have you read Facebook's ["Pixel Troubleshooting" page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-troubleshooting)?

Comment: Yes, I've read there notes and a few articles here and on other blogs. One clue is with the Pixel Verification chrome extension, I get a warning that the "pixel took too long to load", which could be why I'm not seeing the data reported back appropriately.